# The meaning of singleton and existence of $\{\varnothing, \{ \varnothing \}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't understand difference between $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$.
What is difference between $x$ and set that has only $x$ as element?
I think the concept of set is meaningful when it has more than 1 element.
If "$\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing \}$ is different" is right, then I have another question.
When we see the set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}, \varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ exist simultaneously. It means two empty sets exist. One empty set exists as $\varnothing$ itself and one empty set exists as element of $\{\varnothing\}$. I can't understand this situation. What am i misunderstanding?

Comment: There are probably an infinite list of questions like this on the site already. Here are a few quick links. [One](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454814), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202782/), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65599), [four](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744571/), [five](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255726/)... and there are more. Many many many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of sets as bags. $\varnothing$ is an empty bag. $\{\varnothing\}$ is a bag with an empty bag within it. Therefore the outermost bag is not empty: It has a bag inside it.

Also, with this analogy, we have that $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ a bag is containing an empty bag and a bag with an empty bag within it.

Answer (score 1):

The void set $\varnothing$ has no elements.

The set $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element: the void set $\varnothing$.

The set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ has two elements : the void set $\varnothing$ and the set  $\{\varnothing\}$.

The key fact is that a set (void or not) is **a different thing with respect to his elements** and can be element of another set.